# Firebase data consumption on Android

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

(Translated by Google)

Hello

I have made an app in Cordova that uses Firebase (Database and Storage)

Recently, my app used 1Gb of data in a few days (see picture)

By my calculations, the number of bytes sent and received, with own data ({Name: John, Date: 2017-07-14} for example), is only 500 / 600Mb

And the rest?
Is the sum of the headers of each communication?
Is there anything else?

How could I get to control or calculate that myself?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The [database profiler tool](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) will give you some insights.

Comment: Note that there is more data going over the wire than just the JSON. For one the paths for the data take space, then add SSL handshakes, keep-a-lives and protocol overhead. If your actual data sent is 600MB then 1GB including all the other factors sounds pretty reasonable.